# Leitura de arquivo texto armazenado na pasta raw através de uma classe de usuário

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um código de teste que funciona bem.
A função do teste é ler um arquivo texto que está numa pasta res\raw.
Ele lê o arquivo texto sem problemas e estampa seu conteúdo linha a linha através do Toast.

O código funcional é o seguinte:

```
package com.example.teste;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //------------------------------------------------
        Button bt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                InputStream ins = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResource(MainActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier("raw/teste","raw", getPackageName()) );
                InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(ins);
                BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
                String line;
            try {
                    while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }//onClick
        });//bt.setOnClick
    }//onCreate
    //**********************************************************
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }//onCreateOptions

}//classe
```

A minha intenção, entretanto, é fazer um reaproveitamento do código, uma vez que em várias partes de uma futura aplicação eu iria aproveitar a leitura de vários arquivos texto.

Então, quis criar uma classe, a fim de que, após instanciada, lesse arquivos diferentes, quando passasse a um método o nome do arquivo desejado.
Só me interessaria, então, a parte de localização, abertura e leitura do arquivo.

Assim, criei a classe da seguinte forma:

```
 package com.example.teste;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class TestaLeituraArquivo extends Activity {
    Context gblContext;
//--------------------------construtor-----------------
    public TestaLeituraArquivo(Context context){
        this.gblContext=context;
    }//construtor
//---------------------------------método de leitura---------------------------
        public void leArquivo(String strCaminhoNomeArquivo){
                InputStream ins = gblContext.getResources().openRawResource(gblContext.getResources().getIdentifier(strCaminhoNomeArquivo,"raw", getPackageName()) );
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(ins);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
            String line;
        try {
                while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
    Toast.makeText(gblContext, line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(gblContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }//leArquivo
    }//Classe
```

Uma vez que tenho esta classe dentro do mesmo pacote, vou modificar o código inicial, o primeiro lá de cima, a fim de que eu possa aproveitar o benefício da classe criada:

```
 package com.example.teste;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //------------------------------------------------
            Button bt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TestaLeituraArquivo tl = new TestaLeituraArquivo(MainActivity.this);
tl.leArquivo("raw/teste");
                }//onClick
            });//bt.setOnClick
        }//onCreate
        //**********************************************************
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }//onCreateOptions

    }//classe
```

Ou seja, apenas retirei da MainActivity, no click do botão, todo o código que funcionava na leitura do arquivo e passei para o método da classe criada, levando em consideração a passagem do Context que chamava.

O problema que enfrento é que a aplicação 'crasha' e o Try/catch não me avisa nada.

O log de erros mostra alguns erros, mas nada que indique o método em si. Fala de ausência de comunicação com o site da google, problemas com a parte de telefonia, etc.

Onde estou cometendo um erro?

O log de erros é

```
02-13 10:44:19.512: E/PowerManagerService(2486): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
02-13 10:45:36.953: E/PowerManagerService(2486): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
02-13 10:51:17.559: E/SensorManager(2583): unregisterListener: com.android.phone.AccelerometerListener$1@47bcf058
02-13 10:51:17.750: E/LogsProvider(19112): onCreate()
02-13 10:51:18.109: E/RingtoneManager(2583): getRingtone : content://settings/system/ringtone, streamType : -1
02-13 10:51:18.121: E/RingtoneManager(2583): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/13
02-13 10:51:18.121: E/RingtoneManager(2583): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/13
02-13 10:51:18.195: E/SettingsProvider(2486): openAssetFile uri: content://settings/system/ringtone, mode=r
02-13 10:51:18.195: E/SettingsProvider(2486): ringtoneType : 1
02-13 10:51:18.195: E/RingtoneManager(2486): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/13
02-13 10:51:18.195: E/RingtoneManager(2486): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/13
02-13 10:51:18.195: E/SettingsProvider(2486): soundUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/13
02-13 10:51:18.481: E/RingtoneManager(2583): getActualDefaultRingtoneUri : content://media/internal/audio/media/13
02-13 10:51:18.481: E/RingtoneManager(2583): Uri.parse(uriString) : content://media/internal/audio/media/13
02-13 10:51:18.492: E/AudioService(2486): sendVolumeUpdate   VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION  streamType =  2
02-13 10:51:19.277: E/PowerManagerService(2486): reset countdown Timer for PhoneAPP
02-13 10:51:20.500: E/AudioService(2486): sendVolumeUpdate   VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION  streamType =  2
02-13 10:51:21.731: E/SensorManager(2486): registerListener 7:gp2a Proximity Sensor delay:240
02-13 10:51:21.734: E/SensorManager(2583): registerListener 0:SMB380 delay:240
02-13 10:51:21.738: E/SensorManager(2583): =======>>>Sensor Thread RUNNING <<<========
02-13 10:51:22.398: E/SensorManager(2486): unregisterListener: com.android.server.PowerManagerService$11@47b904c0
02-13 10:51:22.582: E/SensorManager(2486): registerListener 7:gp2a Proximity Sensor delay:240
02-13 10:51:23.477: E/SensorManager(2486): unregisterListener: com.android.server.PowerManagerService$12@47b90578
02-13 10:51:23.512: E/SensorManager(2486): unregisterListener: android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@47da0520
02-13 10:51:23.922: E/WifiService(2486): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
02-13 10:51:36.535: E/WifiService(2486): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
02-13 10:51:36.535: E/WifiService(2486): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
02-13 10:51:55.660: E/SensorManager(2486): registerListener 4:gp2a Light Sensor delay:240
02-13 10:51:55.934: E/SensorManager(2486): registerListener 0:SMB380 delay:60
02-13 10:51:56.559: E/WifiService(2486): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
02-13 10:51:56.559: E/WifiService(2486): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
02-13 10:51:59.219: E/SensorManager(2486): unregisterListener: com.android.server.PowerManagerService$12@47b90578
02-13 10:51:59.246: E/SensorManager(2486): unregisterListener: android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@47da0520
02-13 10:51:59.434: E/WifiService(2486): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
02-13 10:52:40.289: E/SensorManager(2486): registerListener 4:gp2a Light Sensor delay:240
02-13 10:52:40.555: E/SensorManager(2486): registerListener 0:SMB380 delay:60
02-13 10:52:41.090: E/SensorManager(2486): unregisterListener: com.android.server.PowerManagerService$11@47b904c0
02-13 10:52:41.723: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:41.762: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:41.816: E/PowerManagerService(2486): reset countdown Timer for PhoneAPP
02-13 10:52:41.848: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:41.918: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:42.020: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:42.020: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:42.180: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:42.243: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:42.352: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:42.392: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 10:52:44.856: E/SensorManager(2583): unregisterListener: com.android.phone.AccelerometerListener$1@47bcf058
02-13 10:52:57.398: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 10:53:19.419: E/PowerManagerService(2486): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
02-13 10:53:48.957: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 10:55:23.664: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 10:56:23.383: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 10:57:05.449: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 10:58:05.168: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:01:55.379: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:03:32.785: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:03:55.887: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:05:33.266: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:06:00.133: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19272): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:08:18.781: E/libnetutils(2486): dhcp start cmd 11 : [dhcpcd:-ABK] 
02-13 11:08:19.012: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(2486): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
02-13 11:08:19.844: E/dalvikvm(19408): Could not find class 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.plus.provider.PlusProvider.a
02-13 11:08:22.609: E/SPPClientService(19480): ============PushLog. commonIsShipBuild. stop!
02-13 11:08:22.625: E/SPPClientService(19480): [PushClientApplication] Push log off : This is Ship build version
02-13 11:08:23.332: E/dalvikvm(19491): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method xg.b
02-13 11:08:23.332: E/dalvikvm(19491): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method xg.c
02-13 11:08:27.352: E/dalvikvm(19514): Could not find class 'android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder', referenced from method J.a.g
02-13 11:18:59.789: E/TalkProvider(2627): replaceContactWithContactId: contactId==0!!! meu@gmail.com, acct=1
02-13 11:18:59.805: E/TalkProvider(2627): insert presence failed for account=1 username=meu@gmail.com client_type=2 status= priority=0 mode=3
02-13 11:19:58.402: E/dalvikvm(19408): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method xg.b
02-13 11:19:58.406: E/dalvikvm(19408): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method xg.c
02-13 11:20:01.215: E/dalvikvm(19727): Could not find class 'android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder', referenced from method J.a.g
02-13 11:20:36.645: E/PowerManagerService(2486): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
02-13 11:22:34.746: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19762): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:23:08.363: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19762): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:27:38.953: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19762): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:28:24.680: E/Mms/SmsReceiverService(19762): [SMS]Receiver handleMessage : Action =android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED
02-13 11:35:14.977: E/PowerManagerService(2486): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
02-13 11:36:57.973: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.051: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.121: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.215: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.277: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.289: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.439: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.516: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.582: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.664: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.739: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.808: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.902: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:58.966: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:59.056: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:59.056: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:59.201: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:36:59.290: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:37:01.778: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:37:03.735: E/imdg81(2486): IsShutDownStarted()
02-13 11:37:12.348: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(2486): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
02-13 11:37:13.613: E/WifiHW(2486): [WIFI] Unload Driver
02-13 11:37:13.918: E/LogsProvider(19971): onCreate()
02-13 11:37:15.387: E/FlurryAgent(19914): Post to http://ads.flurry.com/v4/getAds.do caught IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ads.flurry.com
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950): Error sending ping
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.googleadservices.com:80
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1057)
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1373)
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at com.google.ads.conversiontracking.a.run(SourceFile:168)
02-13 11:37:16.805: E/GoogleConversionPing(19950):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: Amigos, acabei de postar, mas acho que já resolvi o problema. Está na classe _TestaLeituraArquivo_, no método _leArquivo()_. Especificamente na linha dos dois _Toast_: quando troquei o contexto _gblContext_ para _this_ funcionou.

Comment: Desculpem-me, as não achei a solução, não. Eu cometi um engano. Eu continuo com o problema.

Comment: Provavelmente seu problema é com o `Context` tente implementa-lo de uma maneira diferente.

Comment: Por favor, poste o log de erro mesmo não tendo encontrado a linha exata.

Comment: Pus o log de erros após os códigos apresentados. Grato.

Comment: Caro Paulo Roberto, já tentei de alguns jeitos, mas dá sempre o mesmo erro, que não sei qual é. Este é o maior problema, não saber qual o erro exato.

Answer (score 2):

Pesquisando bastante, descobri um jeito de fazer funcionar e tudo tem a ver com o que sugeriu o Paulo Roberto: é um problema de Context.

Não sei se é a melhor técnica, mas ponho aqui apenas para aqueles que porventura venham a ter este tipo de problema e pelo menos provocar uma discussão boa para todos.

A mudança principal é que alterei o construtor da classe do usuário, o daquela que criei.

Neste código, ele passa a receber o contexto da classe inicial e esta variável-contexto passa a ser usada em todas as linhas de código que exigiam essa referência.

O código inicial com uma ligeira modificação é:

```
[...]
//------------------------------------------------
        Button bt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//Veja abaixo dois parâmetros no construtor: o caminho-nome do arquivo e o Context desta activity que instancia a classe
//---------
                Teste t = new Teste("raw/teste",MainActivity.this);//construção
//--------
            t.leArquivo();//método que executa a leitura do arquivo texto no objeto 't'
//---------
            }//onClick
        });//bt.setOnClick
[...]
```

Agora, vamos à classe do usuário:

```
public class Teste extends Activity {
    String strGblCaminhoNomeArquivo="";//variável 'global' do caminho-nome do arquivo
    Context gblContext;//variável 'global' do contexto recebido
//----------construtor
    public Teste(String strCaminhoNomeArquivo, Context context){
        this.strGblCaminhoNomeArquivo=strCaminhoNomeArquivo;
        this.gblContext=context;

    }//construtor
    //---------------------------

/*aqui no método é que o cuidado precisa ser tomado: gblContext teve de ser posto...
*..antes de getResources e de getPackageName().
*Do mesmo mesmo modo, teve de ser posto no Toast também.
*/
public void leArquivo(){
             InputStream ins = gblContext.getResources().openRawResource(gblContext.getResources().getIdentifier(this.strGblCaminhoNomeArquivo,"raw", gblContext.getPackageName()) );
                 InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(ins);
         BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
         String line;
     try {
             while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
 Toast.makeText(gblContext, line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

          } catch (Exception e) {
             Toast.makeText(gblContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }//leArquivo
}//class
```

Feito isto, tive sucesso em exibir cada linha do arquivo sem erro algum.

Comment: Eu ia te sugerir isso, porém eu odeio variáveis globais, e aposto que muita gente aqui também odeia, e não vi nenhuma outra maneira de fazer, por isso nem respondi ;P mas foi boa a tua sacada, a mesma que a minha haha :) - e sobre responder a sua propria pergunta, sim! você tanto pode como deve fazer isto sempre que achar a resposta para o seu problema.

Comment: Se eu tivesse posto _private String strGblCaminhoArquivo;_ e _private Context gblContext;_ talvez ficasse melhor, não?

Comment: É que na verdade não vai mudar muita coisa. Todas as variáveis que você declarar lá em cima na `Activity` você vai poder acessar de qualquer lugar da sua `Activity` que você estiver, por isso não é necessario nem o `this.` na frente :p

Comment: Sim, uso o _this_ para ficar bem claro a 'força' da variável. Mas dentro da mesma classe esse pseudo escopo 'global' não faz muito mal, não acha? Ou tem alguma implicação que eu deveria saber?

Comment: Variáveis globais só não são utilizadas pelo fato que elas podem gerar conflitos, ou você pode alterar o valor delas não intencionalmente causando diversos problemas, variáveis locais são sempre melhor recomendadas pelo fato que elas são forçadas a serem utilizadas apenas para uma funcionalidade e impedindo o uso para outra funcionalidade. Mas no seu caso acredito que não vá ter problema, a não ser que você eventualmente venha a adicionar mais variáveis a sua `Activity` aí talvez possa gerar uma confusão.

Answer (score 1):

Quando há a necessidade de utilizar a pasta \res\raw em algum dos meu projetos eu utilizo da seguinte forma.

```
 InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.teste);
```

Toda vez que você coloca um arquivo na pasta raw automaticamente o sistema cria um ID na classe R para esse arquivo, logo, quando você utiliza desta forma fica bem mais difícil acontecer erro de I/O

Sugiro que mude as assinaturas do metodo para trabalho com o IDs do aruqivo raw como por exemplo

```
public void lerArquivo(int idResources){...}
```

Com essa alteração a chamada do método deve ser:

```
obj.lerArquivo(R.raw.teste);
```

Ao meu ver fica mais fácil de trabalhar.

Mais informações [Android - Provinding Reources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: Caro Clebao, isto me causa uma economia de código, conforme você disse, por um lado, mas me obriga a fazer mais código para descobrir, a partir do nome na pasta raw, o id do arquivo. Não ficaria a mesma coisa?

Comment: Mas os arquivos da sua pasta raw não são fixos? ou você faz download de arquivos por demanda?

Comment: Por demanda, Clebao. Eu quero ler o conteúdo da pasta, que poderá ser móvel na quantidade de arquivos. Não quero engessar os tais, uma vez que a aplicação, em si, terá vários 'sabores' em apks independentes, com quantidade de arquivos textos diferentes.

Comment: Nesse caso eu recomendo você trabalhar com getResources().getIdentifier("raw/teste","raw", getPackageName()), logo ficaria basicamente InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource( getResources().getIdentifier("raw/teste","raw", getPackageName()) );

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, Clebao, mas não adiantou. Continuando tendo a 'exceção', sem nada de novo no log de erros.

Comment: Pelo sue logcat que você colou na pergunta não consegui identificar o erro, coloque o try cat o e.printStackTrace() e cole novamente o logcat.